# Where is the appropriate place to setup common cmake configuration settings?

Tags: c++, cmake

I've been trying to figure out and adopt the latest cmake best practices, as I'm setting up a large project. Several people have advocated what NOT to put in your cmake files. In general, it seems to boil down to (paraphrasing):

> CMake files should just describe what's required for a target to build, but not make assumptions about anything else.

This all makes sense, however, this leads to the question:

**Where *should* you define all of the "optional" settings, if not in the cmake scripts?**

Also, it seems different if we're just talking about a library, vs an application that's dependent on a lot of libraries.

If you're just building a small library, this all seems fine, whoever uses the library is responsible for deciding all of these extra details.

But when building a larger application with many dependencies, it'd be nice to define all of these settings somewhere. In most build systems you get common configurations like debug and release builds. CMake seems to have standard support for "Debug", "Release", "MinSizeRel", "RelWithDebInfo" (I can never remember the abbreviations by the way), but none of these are enforced, so you might just get an empty string.

And even if you intend to respect these, do you just check the build config and set everything in the root cmake script or what?

As a specific example: My project depends on a bunch of 3rd party libraries, and instead of building them all as part of the project, I am trying to pre-build them.

So to make it simple, I currently have a build script which standardizes how I build all of the 3rd party libraries:

```
cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=OFF \
  -DBUILD_STATIC_LIBS:BOOL=ON \
  -DCMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE=On \
  -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${install_prefix} \
  -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="${DIST}" $@ ${CMAKE_SRC_DIR}
```

However this build script is bash, and it's not exactly portable. There are better options right?

I don't expect the other developers of the project to have to memorize a lot of arguments to pass to cmake to build the project the way it was intended.

Comment: Too many questions in one post, some of them are unrelated. "I've seen there's ccmake and cmake-gui, but how do you define the initial values that will appear in these?" - Options are normally created with `set(<var> <value> CACHE ...)` or `option(<var> <value> ...)`. Here `<value>` is the initial (default) value for the options.

Comment: using a toolchain file is a good start. The cmake manual covers how to express intent in a cross-platform way. Personally I use the ruslo/polly toolchains available on github and ruslo/hunter to pull in 3rd-party libraries (and build them with the same toolchain as the main project).